# Using ode23 in MATLAB: Value not given at endpoint

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve differential equations using ode23 in MATLAB but in the given problem, the value given is different from the endpoint. For example: y'+y=2, y(0)=0, t on [-2,10]. ode23 expects a y0 but in this case, I need y(0)=0 and not y(-2)=0. How can I change the parameters of ode23 so that it still tells me the values on the interval [-2,10] but also with y(0)=0?

Comment: Is this homework for a class on PDEs or a class on numerics/MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your problem and solve

```
    " y'(t) = f(t,y(t)) on (0,10] , y(0) = 0 "    (a)
```

and

```
    " y'(t) = f(t,y(t)) on [-2,0) , y(0) = 0 , "    (b)
```

where (a) directly fits ode23, while (b) has to be rewritten by a variable transform `t := -t` to give

```
    " y'(t) = -f(t,y(t)) on (0,2] , y(0) = 0 . "
```

As ode23 bases on single step methods, the approach of splitting the integration interval is legit.